# How kerberos key distribution protocol prevents replay attack ?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, cryptographic-attack

How kerberos key distribution protocol prevents replay attack ?

Comment: http://users.tkk.fi/u/autikkan/kerberos/AIWSC03_kerberos_replay_attacks.pdf ?

Comment: should this be closed ? I don't know enough about the underlying topic to figure if it's out of scope or not.

Comment: (Possible places to consider from reposting it if it gets closed here are: Math.SE and Security.SE)

Comment: In principle: By including a time-stamp in the initial encrypted message and requiring that the first response includes that time-stamp incremented by one (verifying that the client was able to decrypt the message). This assumes that clocks are kept fairly well synchronised, which is not valid for modern globally distributed systems.